# The sick vs. The injured

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, phrase-requests, differences

I'm not a native English speaker so I don't quite understand the nuance of these two words.

When talking about various injuries of an individual or a group of people, which is the right word to use?

To explain more, if a group of people are hurt because of an accident or physically hurt can you say "The sick have been transported to the hospital"? or "The sick are members of the association" etc. Because the my language to English dictionary says "sick" is universally or collectively used when talking about patients or people who are ill or hurt.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: An *injured* person is a *sick* person in the sense their health is not OK. Doesn't work the other way round.

Comment: No - if *a group of people are hurt because of an accident* we refer to them as ***injured*** or ***wounded***. In general, ***sick*** people are people who have ***diseases***. In some contexts we need to refer to *people with health problems* without distinguishing between those with injuries and those with diseases, in which case it's *possible* to call them all ***sick***, but we generally try to avoid that anyway (often, they're all just ***patients*** receiving / needing medical treatment).